# JQUERY check file exist fails with absolute path

Tags: jquery

I need to check if a file exists before performing operations.
To do this I did it this way.

```
var file = 'file/user/foo.pdf';

$.get(file)
     .done(function()
     {
       // do something
     })
     .fail(function()
     {
     alert("The resource is currently unavailable");
})
```

This works very well, but with the absolute path (PHP DOCUMENT_ROOT) it returns false

```
var file = 'c:/program/ep/www/project/file/user/foo.pdf';
```

How could I fix this problem? thanks

Comment: That sounds like a security issue, if that was possible you could read any file from the client's hard disk.

Comment: JavaScript won't have access to the file system. It will only be able to retrieve files that exist in a/the website. Therefore, the context of the retrieval must be from within the website.

Comment: You need to use paths relative to your web server's root directory. Actually, what is it you're trying to do? What are you doing to the PDF?

Comment: Now I understand. the habit of using the absolute path with php .. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for security reasons javaScript won't have access to the file system

may be you want to do this , the url to localhost or 127.0.0.1 or your ip:

```
var file = 'http://localhost/project/file/user/foo.pdf';
var file = 'http://127.0.0.1/project/file/user/foo.pdf';
```